# Error al utilizar map con firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, map, firestore

Estoy tratando de seguir un tutorial donde se crea una app en React tipo chat para lo cual se utiliza Firebase. El problema es que este tutorial es de antes que Firebase actualice al SDK 9 y su codigo quedó deprecado. Intenté ir reemplazando por las nuevas formas que se utilizan desde ahora pero no logro hacer que funcione el código. En definitiva deberia mostrarme los mensajes alojados en una database de firestore pero no estoy pudiendo lograrlo.

Adjunto el código del tutorial que sí funciona

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { db, auth } from '../firebase'
import SendMessage from './SendMessage'
import SignOut from './SignOut'

function Chat() {
    const scroll = useRef()
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection('messages').orderBy('createdAt').limit(50).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            setMessages(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
        })
    }, [])
    return (
        <div>
            <SignOut />
            <div className="msgs">
                {messages.map(({ id, text, photoURL, uid }) => (
                    <div>
                        <div key={id} className={`msg ${uid === auth.currentUser.uid ? 'sent' : 'received'}`}>
                            <img src={photoURL} alt="" />
                            <p>{text}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
            <SendMessage scroll={scroll} />
            <div ref={scroll}></div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Chat
```

Y mi código

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {app} from '../firebase.js'
import SignOut from './SignOut'
import {getFirestore, onSnapshot, collection, query, orderBy, QuerySnapshot, limit, docs, doc} from 'firebase/firestore'

const Chat = () => {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
    useEffect(()=>{
        const db = getFirestore(app)
        const q = query(collection(db, "messages"), orderBy('createdAt'), limit(50))
        const x = onSnapshot(q, (QuerySnapshot)=>{
            setMessages(QuerySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, data: doc.data()})))
        })
        x();
    }, [])
    return (
        <div>
            <SignOut></SignOut>
            {messages.map(({id, text, photoURL})=>(
                <div key={id}>
                    <img src={photoURL} alt="" />
                    <p>{text}</p>
                </div>
            ))}
            Chat
        </div>
    )
}

export default Chat
```

Comment: ¿Algún error? Describe el comportamiento del código en la pregunta: error, no hace nada, crea algo con una estructura indebida, etc.

Comment: El error es que no muestra en mi app los mensajes que estan alojados en la base de datos